# Label queries containing a specific word as the specific word in R

Tags: r

My sample dataset looks like bellow.

```
Queries <- c("apple firm","banana firm","organe firm")
Rank <- c(1,2,3)
data <- data.frame(Queries,Rank)
```

I have another list like this.

```
List <- c("apple","banana")
```

I need to create a new Column "Label". If Queries contains the words in the list, they should be tagged as the words. For this sample, the "apple firm" would be tagged as "apple", while the "banana firm" tagged as "banana". Now I am using the grep function, but I need to label every word manually. I am seeking for an automatic way to do this.

Comment: Is the `Name` object the same as `Queries`?

Comment: My bad. It is Queries. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do this without a loop, but here is a potential solution:

```
data$Label <- character(nrow(data))

for (word in List) {
  data$Label[grep(word, data$Queries)] <- word
}
```

Are there Queries that would have more than one Label? This will not work in that case.